# Remove a UIView from superView in numberOfSectionsInTableView method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

So I think this might be a simple problem but I am trying to remove a view from the superview in numberOfSectionsInTableView method. I called

```
[view removeFromSuperview]
```

but the view is still visible. I added the view programmably while I am fetching data from the network and then I want to remove the view once I have data or else keep the view. I have tried to remove it in both numberOfSectionsInTableView and cellForRowAtIndexPath but no success. Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]
I am fetching the data in viewWillAppear method and then within the method of fetching the data, I call [self.tableView reloadData] to update the table after the fetch. This is my other method

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
if (feeds.count >0 ) {
    if(tableView.backgroundView){
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    [hud hide:YES];
    return 1;
}
else {
    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    messageLabel.text = @"We presently do not have any data for your search. Please check back soon";
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:20];
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.fullView addSubview:messageLabel];
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:3];
    return 0;
}
```

}

I am now able to remove the view when there is data but I now want to add a UILabel to my view (called fullView) as shown above when there is no data but I can't add the UILabel. How is that going to be possible?

Comment: You should determine the number of sections your table view should have at the time of fetching data from network and return the appropriate value in numberOfSectionsInTableView method.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: How do you get the value of `view`?

Comment: @Arun, I have update my question to reflect your comments. Thanks

Comment: Have a NSArray which holds the data denoting the number of sections for your table view. So if the array contains 0 elements, table view won't show. Again add your messageLabel to self.fullView and hide that. Whenever you are populating the above array, if there are no entries show the label

Comment: I think feeds is a NSArray object here. So based on its count you can return the appropriate value for numberOfSectionsInTableView. Initialse and add the label to fullView in viewWillAppear and hide it for now. Then show it if feeds.count == 0

Comment: Using @Arun comments, I was able to implement it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

bringSubviewToFront should work, just make sure you're using it correctly. The usage is.

[view bringSubviewToFront: messageLabel];